# Vim wordcount for alphanumeric characters only

Tags: word-processing

I know that vim has a function `wordcount()` that returns a dictionary containing the number of bytes, lines, words etc in the current buffer. The problem I have is that the `words` field of the dict from `wordcount()` seems to include the number of `WORD`s (vim's term for any sequence of chars that are not a whitespace character). For example, given:

```
# a markdown title
```

in a buffer, `wordcount()['words']` returns 4, because the "#" counts as a word to vim. Is there some way I can count **only** the alphanumerical words in a buffer? I know I can use

```
:%s/\w\+//eng
```

but redirecting the output is cumbersome and slow if I want to have a constant word count (say, in the statusline). I need this for writing assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split()` on non-word characters and count the number of resulting words.

```
:let cnt=0 | g/./let cnt+=len(split(getline('.'), '\W\+'))
```

Comment: What does the g/./ bit do? Looks like it must cycle over the lines but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @StevieD `:h :g`